# Backbone.js's Ajax call different behavior in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am facing a weird issue in Firefox. We are loading a page and while calling Routers.initializeRouters(); an ajax request is sent to fetch the data  and loadFormSuccessHandler function populate response into the views.

In case of Chrome, Ajax request waits for views to be initialized then data get populated into the view with ajax response.

In case of Firefox, Ajax request fetch the data and start populating the view and it fails because some of the views still not initialized.

How can I notify ajax request to wait for views to be initialized before populating data.

Any pointers will be helpful.

**Main.js**

```
var Main = {

    treeView : null,
    formView : null,
    mainTabBarView : null,
    currentFieldView : null,
    designModeViewPointer : null,
    carousel : null,
    advancedControlsView : null,

    renderUI : function() {
        Templates.loadTemplateList();
        Utility.initializeFieldHandlerMap();
        Views.showBody();
        Routers.initializeRouters();
        var form = new Models.Form();
        this.formView = Views.showForm('formDetailsDiv', form);
        this.treeView = new Views.TreeView({
            el : $('#controlsTreeDiv'),
            model : null
        });

        this.treeView.getTree().attachEvent("onDblClick",
                ControlBizLogic.formTreeNodeClickHandler);

        Main.mainTabBarView = new Views.TabBarView({
            el : $('#csdOperationsContainer'),
            model : null
        });
        Views.showControlTab('control');
        this.carousel = $('#controlTypesSlider');
        this.carousel.tinycarousel();
        Main.advancedControlsView = new Views.AdvancedPropertiesTabView({
            el : $('#advancedControlProperties'),
            model : null
        });
        // init design mode
        Main.designModeViewPointer = new Views.DesignMode({
            el : $("#design")
        });
        Routers.designModeOnBeforeDragEvent();
        Routers.designModeOnDragEvent();

    }
}

Main.renderUI();
```

**Method with ajax call response**

```
loadForm : function(_id, edit) {
                    $("#formWaitingImage").show();
                    if (Main.formView == null) {
                        Main.formView = Views.showForm('formTab',
                                new Models.Form({
                                    "id" : _id
                                }));

                    }
                    Main.formView.getFormModel().set({
                        id : _id
                    });
                    GlobalMemory.editForm = (edit == "true");
                    Main.formView.getFormModel().fetch({
                        url : 'csdApi/form/' + _id + "/" + edit,
                        success : this.loadFormSuccessHandler
                    });
                    // save as
                },

loadFormSuccessHandler : function(model, response) {
                    var formId = model.get('id');
                    if (formId != undefined && formId != null) {
                        GlobalMemory.editForm = true;
                    }
                    Routers.formEventsRouterPointer.updateUI(model);
                    Routers.formEventsRouterPointer.loadFormulae(Main.formView
                            .getFormModel(), "", "");

                    AdvancedControlPropertiesBizLogic
                            .loadSkipRules(Main.formView.getFormModel());
                    Main.formView.getFormModel().set({
                        skipRules : model.get('skipRules'),
                        id : model.get('id')
                    });
                    Main.advancedControlsView.setTableCss('formulaTable');
                    // Main.mainTabBarView.loadFormSummary();
                    Main.mainTabBarView.getFormSummaryView().displayFormInfo(
                            model.getFormInformation());

                    $("#formWaitingImage").hide();
                    // save form

                    if (!GlobalMemory.editForm) {

                        $('#saveForm').prop("value", " Save As ")
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to specific firefox version and it was fixed in the next firefox release.